# Kак сделать ссылку на другую страницу внутри списка `li`?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Kак сделать ссылку на другую страницу внутри списка `li`? Cо ссылкой `#` (внутри страницы) все ок, вот на другую страницу ни как не получается.

```html
<li class="active nav-item"><a class="scrollto" href="#about">Главная</a></li>
     <li class="active nav-item"><a class="scrollto" href="#alphabet"> </a></li>
     <li class="active nav-item"><a class="scrollto" href="#med"> Аудио файлы</a></li> 
    <li class="active nav-item"><a class="scrollto" href="#additionally">Дополнительно</a></li>
    <li class="active nav-item"><a class="scrollto" href="**faq/index.php**"*>Задавать вопрос</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="active nav-item"><a class="scrollto" href="/faq/index.php">Задавать вопрос</a></li>
```

Обычно это так делают.

Зачем у Вас в ссылке `*`?